# submit data filled in pdf file over a browser plugin (Adobe Acrobat) to the server

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working with a application (Clent-Server architecture) where I need to edit a PDF over a client's browser plugin and send data back to server using Java technologies. I have gone through iText examples, but couldn't find and specific solution to my situation.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I went to the [official iText site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and I looked at the examples and Q&A entries tagged [submit form](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/submit-form). The third entry was [How to edit a PDF embedded in the browser and save the PDF directly to server?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-edit-pdf-embedded-browser-and-save-pdf-directly-server) That question sparkled my curiosity and what a surprise! It was the exact answer to your question! I have a counter-question: *Is it that hard to find the official documentation?*

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Not at all, even you guys have a pretty detailed and comprehensive documentation. Most of the time I am taking help from those only. This was asked because I was not aware that I can call a servlet from PdfAction.createSubmitForm() because the very first parameter is named as "file" and it just didn't clicked me to think beyond.